# can't call the second function in controller codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, controller, clean-urls

I'm new in codeigniter I have problem

I use my OS X Lion, and I use `.htaccess` I can call directly localhost/site_folder/ it works like charm, but I have second function in my controller but I can't directly call that function like this localhost/site_folder/function2

here my controller

```
class My_site extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  }
function index() {
  --some script--
  }
function function2() {
  --some script--
  }
}
```

and it's says url not found, why?

thank you

Comment: Can you put routes code here ? (`config/routes.php`)

Comment: if My_Site is not your default controller I guess you need to call it by `http://localhost/site_folder/my_site/function2`

Comment: @safarov this is my `config/routes $route['default_controller'] = "myshop"`

@Shiplu I already try like you say, but no result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solutions on this forum http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/210578/

Answer (score 1):

The default routing scheme is `example.com/class/function/id/` <sup>[Doc](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)</sup>

If `site_folder` is the folder where you have installed codeigniter, Your url to `function2` would be,

```
http://localhost/site_folder/my_site/function2
```

Comment: I still cannot access..
here for my .htaccess
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`
it is right?

Answer (score 1):

```
  It may be the issue please Check the uri protocol in the config file that should be AUTO.

  Config/config.php ===> $config['uri_protocol']    = 'AUTO';
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mushi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46517189/9583070) codeigniter automatically adds index.php to your 'localhost/site_folder/' which is specified in the config.php file (line 38). So to call the function you would have to go to 'localhost/site_folder/index.php/function2'