# Codeigniter controller not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have create a controller in codeigniter. The problem is that when I hit the controller name and function name in url then Its give me error that 404 not found. I am new to codeigniter and I did not understand where I am going wrong

Here is my controller

```
<?php
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller{

function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
}

function you(){
$this->load->view('home_view');
}

}
?>
```

and my view is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>My First CodeIgniter Practice</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1> HELLO CI Buddy...!</h1>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I am creating my first project on codeigniter and I stuck in this problem.I already try most of the solution from the stackoverflow and after that I asking this question. So Its my request not to add this question to duplicate. I want solution for my problem. any help is appreciable

Thanks

Comment: What URL you wrote in address bar?

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh Thanks for reply but these are not working

Comment: @Hassaan I am using this url localhost/w3crud/Home/index

Comment: Is your view file located in `/application/views/home_view.php`?

Comment: try  localhost/w3crud/index.php/home

Comment: set your default controller in routes.php and make all function `public function`

Comment: @skyyler yes its located in same path

Comment: You don't have `index` function, so use this url: `localhost/w3crud/index.php/home/you`

Comment: @azad chouhan try run only `localhost/w3crud/` and let us know what is coming. Does it display welcome page?? or it showing your home page ??

Comment: When you do changes in domain config in cPanle, .htaccess file inside public_html will be changed, So add these lines along with the changes seen in .htacess: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On  
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


</IfModule>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue may be due to any of the following reason

- First letter of your controller file name should be in capital letter ie Home.php .
- Please check your home page file name
- Use the URL localhost/w3crud/index.php/home/you
  if the issue is in your url then edit your .htaccess file

Answer (score 7):

I think there might be problem with .htaccess file. Do you have .htaccess file in your main project directory and is that written like following ?? If not make that so..

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can't believe I could have missed that in my installation.

Answer (score 3):

While thinking about this problem I wonder this might happened to starters like me
Suppose we have the project in a folder named **codeigniter**. so when typing the url we type something like this `localhost/codeigniter/` and it shows the welcome message.But it automatically adds **index.php** defined in config.php (line 38) after the url like this `localhost/codeigniter/index.php`. So if you don't have mod_rewrite written in .htaccess file don't worry, try this url

`localhost/codeigniter/index.php/home/you`

in your case `home.php` is the controller file and `you` is the method here

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your project on a live server? If yes, then make sure the filename of your controller starts with a upper case letter. It might seem like a silly answer but mind it that I myself spent more than five hours trying to fix the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following

a) Create member function index() in controller and check

b) Which url yor are checking?

b.1) http://localhost/yourproject/index.php/home/you

(localhot: is your server url, yourproject: your project folder, home = your controller file i.e. Home.php and you: your member function.

Comment: i try with index function still not found

Comment: Check one by one
1) Check server is working (http://localhost/ )
2) Check your project default controller is working (http://localhost/yourproject)
If both are working then check your controller file i.e. "Home.php" which is placed on /application/controllers folder. First letter is upper case for new CI

Comment: but i dont need index.php in the url

Comment: This is codeigniter default method. Please check online doc: 
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

To remove index.php from url use .htaccess method. Online Doc:
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

Try as following

```
<?php
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller{

   public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
      $this->load->view('home_view');
    }

}
?>
```

and make sure your `home_view.php` file exist with your code in `application/views` directory. Now you may run URL `http://localhost/w3crud/home/index` to see the desired output

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible causes as to why it is happening. In my case, the cause is about the use of underscores in naming a controller e.g. `My_Custom_Controller`

## routes.php (problematic)

```php
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['my-custom-path'] = 'my_Custom_Controller/landing';
```

So, I was able to fix it by renaming the controller into `Mycustomcontroller` then that was the only time it worked.

## routes.php (functional)

```php
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['my-custom-path'] = 'mycustomcontroller/landing';
```

The naming doesn't follow the suggested naming convention of CodeIgniter but it definitely solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your CI in a subfolder, let say c:/xampp/htdocs/somemap/ci
Change your .htaccess to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /ci/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ci/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please note the /ci/